# Error occurred when the Magento extension installation

Tags: magento-1.9

When the process of installation in magento connect manager the following error will be occurred:

**"community/Amar_Profile: Unknown cipher in list: TLSv1"**

Here is the extension links

https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/custome-account-profile-13594.html

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try changing:

```
$this->curlOption(CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST, 'TLSv1');
```

to

```
$this->curlOption(CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1);
```

in file:

downloader/lib/Mage/HTTP/Client/Curl.php